# The line edit widget shows nothing

Tags: qt

I've recently started learning Qt and I'm a beginner of it now. So as first example for myself I wrote the following simple example.

The example is named *Calculator*. It now only has two *buttons* an a *line edit*. It's here:

[image]:

My *Calculator.h* is this:

```
#ifndef CALCULATOR_H
#define CALCULATOR_H

#include<QDialog>
#include "ui_Calculator.h"

class Calculator : public QDialog, public Ui::Calculator
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Calculator(QWidget* parent = 0);

private slots:
   void myslot();
};

#endif // CALCULATOR_H
```

And the *Calculator.cpp* is this:

```
#include <QtWidgets>
#include "calculator.h"

Calculator::Calculator(QWidget *parent)
    :QDialog(parent)
{
    setupUi(this);

 connect(oneButton,SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(myslot()));
}

void Calculator::myslot(){
    lineEdit -> setText("1");
}
```

And this is the *main.cpp*:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDialog>

#include "ui_Calculator.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    Ui::Calculator ui;
    QDialog* dialog = new QDialog;
    ui.setupUi(dialog);
    dialog -> show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

The program runs fine without any error. But when I click on *1* button, nothing will be printed/shown in the *line edit*. Why please?
And what part of my program should I change to solve the issue please?

Comment: where is defined the variable lineEdit ?

Comment: I have defined it by the designer. and it exists in the _ui_Calculator.h_.

Comment: can you change your `connect` call to the new syntax shown here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html If you have some problems with the signal slot connections this will more likely show some compiler errors

Comment: @Hayt: thanks for the comment. I'm reading the book C++ GUI Programming Using Qt4 second edition. The connec style is fine according to it. Have you tested the program on your machine please?

Comment: @franky are you using qt5? the new styles have some advantages over the "old" qt4 styles.

Comment: @Hayt. Yes, the book is about Qt4 but the compiler is _Qt Creator 3.6.0-.

Comment: You can use the book to teach you basic Qt but you maybe should in parallel check out the help of the Qt website to see what has changed. ( note: there is help for qt-4.8 and qt-5. You can see which one you are using in the URL )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting up the wrong class in your main.

You should use your custom `Calculator` class and not `QDialog`.

`setupUi` only initializes your elements but your code in `Calculator` never gets called. Your main should look like this:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    Calculator calc; //using your Calculator class.
    calc.show();    
    return app.exec();
}
```

And don't include `ui_calculator.h` but `calculator.h`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Should I do the works this way: 1- Changing the main body to your version. 2- Removing _ui_calculator.h_ in the _Calculator.h_. Yes?

Comment: @franky yes you need to do both. Without the changed header the code will not compile.

Comment: I did the above works but I get errors: _C:\Users\CS\Documents\Qt\Calculator\main.cpp:9: error: 'Calculator' was not declared in this scope
        Calculator calc; //using your Calculator class.
        ^_            AND        _C:\Users\CS\Documents\Qt\Calculator\main.cpp:10: error: 'calc' was not declared in this scope
        calc.show();
        ^_

Comment: @franky do you include calculator.h before the main?